# Using a scanner with thin client, RemoteFX redirect not working

Tags: hyper-v, rdp, usb, thin-client

So I work IT for a small company and we are testing and considering rolling out Dell WYSE Rx0L thin clients to our employees. So far all is going well, except for our set up for our Data Entry dept.

For that specific dept I need to set up a handheld bar code scanner and an HP Deskjet 8200 desktop scanner. The bar code scanner worked in the RDP session flawlessly without me having to do anything. The problem is the HP 8200. I cannot get the RDP session to recognize it.

I've installed it on the WYSE client, and it shows in devices. I set up the RemoteFX USB redirect and when I go into the RDP Options > Local Resources > More Devices > RemoteFX it does show the HP scanner. Still no love in the RDP session though.

I've been looking online for 2 days now and it must be a common issue because there are a plethora of PAID solutions out there... but I'm looking for something more in the FREE category. I've seen several forums where people just simply says "i got it to work" but don't say how, and all of the other solutions are to buy software. I've also read that I should check the wnos.ini file, but I can't seem to find it on the client nor would I know what to do with it if I did find it.

Any guidance (that doesn't involve buying more things) would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Not really my area, but have you made sure to install the driver for the device in OS of the RDS server?

Comment: @AidanFinn Thanks for the reply, sorry this took a bit to get back we kinda tabled that project for a while, but we're back to it now. Yes I installed the driver on both the RDS server and the client